# Inline Linking Copyrighted Material

Tags: copyright, trademark

So there are some similar posts but not really with answers that fit to my problem. I run a site posting about newest announcements, let´s say Nike announces a new pair of shoes.

Now I want to write about this, but I can't find images anywhere except from Nike's announcement or other websites writing about it. Now these other websites seem to rely on the doctrine of Fair Use.

I live in Europe, Germany and we do not have fair use here, that's why I read a bit more and thought about if inline linking, lets say a img tag referring to the src on Nike's media servers instead of copying it to my own server and showing it from there. This seems like a borderline topic but I do not want to take a big risk that's why I am asking for a opinion/answer here.

Comment: In practise Nike will *love* you amplifying their publicity.  This is what their (very expensive) PR people are trying to make happen.  Thus in practise, there will be no comeback, even if you put the images on your own server.  (Not an answer, because I don't know what the *legal* situation is.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes thats the common approach to simply do it without caring, but I would like to be on the save side of law since it can get very expensiv otherwise

Comment: It's very, *very* unlikely to get expensive.  The first stage will be a "cease and desist" letter or email; to which you promptly reply "Oh, sorry; I have taken the images down.  I won't do it again"

Comment: @MartinBonner Do you think its like that? We also would only take official Images and no images from photographs that made a image of the product, mh i readed it can cost like 25k+€ if you take the image without permission?

Comment: "...a img tag referring to the src on Nike's media servers instead of copying it to my own server..." You're talking about hotlinking: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/can-you-be-accused-of-hotlinking-copyright-violation-if-you-use-an-iframe

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I readed that already, but its US related and also 80% of the answer is copy paste from wikipedia

Comment: I think I covered the EU perspective in this answer: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/38612/3209