# Hotlinking online radio streams

Tags: copyright, internet, european-union, radio

I want to create an online radio directory, with the ability to play the radio stations on my website. For sure, I will only add the radio stations which are broadcasting online and are offering an URL for external player.

Is it legally to "embed" radio stations which are offering an URL to listen in an external player but not specifically an "embed" code?

Thank you!

PS: initially it looked like image hot linking for me (which I know is not always legal)... but I think it is not the same case here because the radio stations are offering a link for external player (so my website should be considered as an external player - why not!?)...

Comment: See also: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/can-you-be-accused-of-hotlinking-copyright-violation-if-you-use-an-iframe